# Can I use a pointer array to access the data stored in an array with different rank in Fortran?

Tags: pointers, fortran

Suppose I have an array:

```
REAL,TARGET :: X(3,3)
```

I would like to use a pointer array like:

```
REAL,POINTER :: P(:)
```

To sequentially access the data stored in X

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Pointer rank remapping allows an array pointer to reference a simply contiguous or rank one target, that is of a different rank to the pointer, using a form of the pointer association statement.  For the example in the question:

```
P(1:9) => X
```